# Referring to the current bookmark in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch, dvcs

I am using bookmarks in mercurial to emulate a git branches-like workflow.

One thing I'm finding is that whenever I push, I invariably want to push just the current bookmark. Rather than typing

```
hg push -B <bookmark_name>
```

all the time, I'd like to alias `hg push` to just push the current bookmark. To do that, I need a way of referring to the current bookmark without mentioning its name. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

I understand it was asked two years ago, but I found this page in Google and none of the answers helped. So here's what did the trick for me (Linux):

```
[alias]
currentbranch = !cd `$HG root` && cat .hg/bookmarks.current
pushb = !$HG push -B `$HG currentbranch`
```

cd is required for this to work from non-root directories.

Answer (score 2):

Current bookmark name stored in `.hg/bookmarks.current` file of your repository. As an alias you can use something like this:

```
pushb = push -B `cat .hg/bookmarks.current`
```

Also note that when you update you repository state to any other revision, there won't be file `.hg/bookmarks.current`.

Comment: This also doesn't work for me: I get `hg pushb: invalid arguments`. I don't think `.hgrc` supports `\`...\``-style command substitution.

Comment: It can work, probably, but only as **shell-alias** (haven't Tux in hands for tests)

Answer (score 2):

OK, platform independent solution, somehow ugly

```
pushb = push -B `hg log --template "{bookmarks}\n" -r "bookmark() & ."`
```

or, with nested command in more natural way it must be: `hg parents --template="{bookmarks}\n"`

Ugly because pure Mercurial-way using nested shell-aliases in hgrc

```
[alias]
cb = !$HG log --template "{bookmarks}\n" -r "bookmark() & ."
pushb = push -B cb
```

does not work for me

```
>hg pushb
...
bookmark cb does not exist on the local or remote repository!
```

**Edit**

Long time later, with new solution. According to `hg help push`

> If -B/--bookmark is used, the specified bookmarked revision, its
>       ancestors, and the bookmark will be pushed to the remote repository.
>       **Specifying "." is equivalent to specifying the active bookmark's name**.

if order to "push the current bookmark" you can use just

`hg push -B .`

Comment: This doesn't work for me: I get `hg pushb: option --template not recognized`.

Comment: @HighCommander4 - try pure `log` directly in Mercurial, exchange order of options: `log -r --template` (it templating supported in your version of HG)

Comment: `hg log --template "{bookmarks}\n" -r "bookmark() & ."` works fine in Mercurial. The problem is that the `hgrc` file does not recognize the `\`` as a special character, it just treats it like a quote, so the command it tries to run is `hg push -B 'hg log --template "{bookmarks}\n" -r "bookmark() & ."'`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (and handles bookmarks with spaces):

```
alias pushb="hg push -B \"\$(hg bookmarks 2> /dev/null | awk '/\*/ { \$1=\"\"; \$NF=\"\"; printf }' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//')\""
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a shell call substitution:

```
hg push -B `hg bookmark --active`
```

This can be put into an alias (see alias section of `hg help config`)

Comment: I also get that with Mercurial 2.4. Perhaps the `--active` option was added in a later version?

Comment: Got confuse by a dev discussion. the next (2.8) may have such flag (currently not in core). Sorry about that.